# Prevent Passphrase request when signing JAR

Tags: java, maven, gnupg, pgp, maven-gpg-plugin

I'm trying to setup my Maven build so that it signs the JAR automatically without the need to manually enter the passphrase however no matter how I try to configure the `maven-gpg-plugin` it either fails or always asks for the passphrase.

I've used [this](http://www.debonair.io/post/maven-cd/) page as guidance on how to set up Maven `settings.xml`:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <gpg.executable>gpg2</gpg.executable>
                <gpg.keyname>${env.GPG_KEY_NAME}</gpg.keyname>
                <gpg.passphrase>${env.GPG_PASS_PHRASE}</gpg.passphrase>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <username>${env.OSSRH_JIRA_USERNAME}</username>
            <password>${env.OSSRH_JIRA_PASSWORD}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

The environment variables above are set in the environment.

And the `maven-gpg-plugin` configuration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859942/how-do-i-get-the-maven-gpg-plugin-to-use-a-passphrase-from-environment-variable) I've tried to set-up the POM as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <gpgArguments>
                        <arg>--pinentry-mode</arg>
                        <arg>loopback</arg>
                    </gpgArguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

But when I build I get the following error:
`gpg: setting pinentry mode 'loopback' failed: Not supported`

I've tried to add `allow-loopback-pinentry` to gpg-agent.conf but the result is the same.
If I remove the `<gpgArguments>` from the Maven plugin configuration then I get the pop-up asking for the passphrase.

I'm using gpg2 version 2.1.11

Comment: Did you run with debug logging (`-X`) and ensure that the `ossrh` profile is enabled? `activeByDefault` does not mean "always active" - it means "active if and only if no other profile is active." The other profile can be elsewhere in your POM, or in a parent POM somewhere.

Comment: No I wasn't explicitly calling the ossrh profile and I didn't realise <activeByDefault> doesn't literally mean 'active by default'. Tried building with -X and can see the passphrase and keyname are being passed in but also see that `useAgent` is also set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs due to the fact I was attempting to use `gpg2` instead of `gpg` as I had assumed that `gpg2` was better (without actually researching). The man page for gpg 2 states:

> In contrast to the standalone command gpg from GnuPG 1.x, which is
>   might be better suited for server and embedded platforms, the 2.x
>   version is commonly installed under the name gpg2 and targeted to the
>   desktop as it requires
>          several other modules to be installed.

`gpg2` is targeted at the desktop and hence I am assuming is 'hard-coded' to ask for the password and I should in fact be using `gpg`.

Answer (score 0):

[Plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html) say default executable is `gpg`. If the profile isn't enabled, is it picking up your desired `gpg2`? `useAgent` == true is default, should be left that way for gpg2 per docs.

For using the agent, try configuring the executable right in the plugin instead of a profile.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>gpg2</executable>
                <gpgArguments>
                    <arg>--pinentry-mode</arg>
                    <arg>loopback</arg>
                </gpgArguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

To do it without the agent, using the `settings.xml` file, try this (based on my reading of the goal and [usage docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/usage.html)):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>gpg2</executable>
                <keyname>${gpg.keyname}</keyname>
                <passphraseServerId>${gpg.keyname}</passphraseServerId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
        <gpg.keyname>${env.GPG_KEY_NAME}</gpg.keyname>
    </properties>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>${env.GPG_KEY_NAME}</id>
            <passphrase>${env.GPG_PASS_PHRASE}</passphrase>
       </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Note, I didn't use the profile as they suggested, because per [Maven profile docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)  (emphasis mine):

> will automatically be active for all builds **unless** another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the previously described methods. **All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config.**

This caused me "fun" debug sessions, and I've seen it catch many other unsuspecting developers too.

Comment: Thanks for the response but still not working. I've checked the profile is active and I can see the keyname and passphraseServerId for the plugin in the debug output but I still get the pop-up asking for the passphrase. I am using a sub-key to sign my artifact but it is the passphrase for the sub key and not the master that it is asking for. Need to sleep on it and try again.