# Build error: Primefaces 11.0.0 release from source

Tags: maven, build, primefaces, release

Build primefaces 11.0.0 release:

> mvn clean install -Prelease -X

```
[DEBUG] Generating signature for primefaces\target\primefaces-parent-11.0.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for PrimeFaces Parent 11.0.0:
[INFO]
[INFO] PrimeFaces Parent .................................. FAILURE [  6.303 s]
[INFO] PrimeFaces ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PrimeFaces Showcase ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] PrimeFaces Selenium ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] PrimeFaces Selenium - Core ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PrimeFaces Selenium - Components ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PrimeFaces Integration Tests ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PrimeFaces CLI ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.873 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-06T13:12:07-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign (sign-artifacts) on project primefaces-parent: Execution sign-artifacts of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign (sign-artifacts) on project primefaces-parent: Execution sign-artifacts of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution sign-artifacts of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.gpg.GpgSigner.generateSignatureForFile (GpgSigner.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.gpg.AbstractGpgSigner.generateSignatureForArtifact (AbstractGpgSigner.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.gpg.GpgSignAttachedMojo.execute (GpgSignAttachedMojo.java:179)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Could be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018765/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-gpg-plugin)?

Comment: After adding skip gpg and frontend in pom.xml, it works. Thanks.

Comment: The js/css resources are not minified with -Prelease. Can this issue be related to the skipped frontend maven plugin? thanks

Comment: It is on master? I am using 11.0.0. We need minified js/css resources for production.

Comment: Don't use `-Prelease` use `-Pminify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the build and minify the resources run this Maven command.

`mvn clean install -Pminify`